# Fetch URL with Javascript interop in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

I am trying to fetch the current URL with a Javascript interop in Blazor, I am trying with this code:

```
string url = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("window.location.href");
```

But it does not work. I have also tried following [this](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/340/working-with-query-strings-in-blazor) guide to do the same thing with the NavigationManager, but then my *navManager* object gets null for unknown reasons (despite injecting it).

How can I achieve this?

My current code is (file is NavMenu.razor): https://pastebin.com/CBHbahDG

Comment: Could you provide some code showing what you’ve tried with the NavigationManager which didn’t work? NavigationManager is the way to get the URL information in Blazor. You don’t need JS interop for this.

Comment: Code attached with edit.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just use an arbitrary JS expression with InvokeAsync. But you can have a simple global JS function e.g.

```
function getUrl() {
    return window.location.href;
}
```

and then call it: `await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getUrl")`.